# Htop installation failed

Tags: freebsd, htop

I'm trying to install the `htop` , but I can't since I'm getting this fatal error:

```
# cd /usr/ports/sysutils/htop && make install clean
===>  Installing for htop-1.0.1
===>   htop-1.0.1 depends on executable: lsof - not found
===>    Verifying install for lsof in /usr/ports/sysutils/lsof
===>  Configuring for lsof-4.86B,6
Creating ./lockf_owner.h from /usr/src/sys/kern/kern_lockf.c
FATAL ERROR: can't read /usr/src/sys/kern/kern_lockf.c
FATAL ERROR: ./lockf_owner.h creation failed (see 00FAQ)
===>  Script "Configure" failed unexpectedly.
Please report the problem to ler@lerctr.org [maintainer] and attach the
"/usr/ports/sysutils/lsof/work/lsof_4.86B.freebsd/config.log" including the
output of the failure of your make command. Also, it might be a good idea to
provide an overview of all packages installed on your system (e.g. an `ls
/var/db/pkg`).
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/sysutils/lsof.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/sysutils/htop.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/sysutils/htop.
```

What does that mean and how can I fix that?

Comment: What does `/usr/ports/sysutils/lsof/work/lsof_4.86B.freebsd/config.log` say?

Comment: Install kernel sources or use package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you look at 00FAQ as was suggested by the error message? 
Question 8.6 describes exactly your situation and how to work around it.

If you don't want to install the Kernel source on your machine, a workaround would be to install the lsof binary package

```
pkg_add -r lsof
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that `lsof` is a dependency of htop, and the problem you're having is that a file can't be read and/or created, there may be a need for `lsof`'s services during the installation. Either install `lsof` or, if it already is installed, create a hardlink for `lsof` in `/usr/ports/sysutils/lsof`.

Answer (score 0):

htop as far as I know has linuxulator as a dependency. What it can't find here is something within your kernel source. Check if there's anything in /usr/src. If not you should check out the source collection, which belongs there, using **csup**.